# can't access remote desktop's opened tcp from local system

Tags: remote-access, windows-server-2012

I can able to login the dedicated server(has Windows server 2012) from local system by Remote Desktop connection. I used IP address and admin password to login dedicated server. I ran tomcat server in dedicated server and deployed my application then I can access my application from dedicated server's browser like

> localhost:8080/myapp

or

> xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/myapp

It was working fine there, but when I tried to access the same app from my local system as

> xx.xx.xx.xx:8080/myapp

It's not working. I ran `netstat -a` to see whether the tcp is running or not in dedicated server , I can see `0.0.0.0:8080 is in Listening state` in dedicated server. Any idea?

Comment: Check if firewall is not blocking your port either on your system or on your server.

Comment: It was firewall blocking the port in server, now I have turned firewall off it's working now. thank you guys.

Answer (score 0):

Also if it's a firewall issue then rather turning the firewall you can write inbound and outbound rule for specific port. Turning your firewall on server is a dangerous compromise with security.